# grep command with two search criteria

Tags: awk, grep

`I have the contents of file as below.

```
<path
action="A"
kind="file">/Demo/svn_dev/src/classes/Util - Copy.cls</path><path
action="D"
kind="file">/Demo/svn_dev/src/classes/Admin.cls</path>
<path action="M"
kind="file">/Demo/svn_dev/src/classes/AdminUtilCtrl.cls</path>
</paths>
<msg>xyz</msg>
```

I need to retrive the path of the file if message contains string "xyz" and action="D"
Here I need to get the out put as /Demo/svn_dev/src/classes/Admin.cls
Can any one help me with grep command syntax. Please let me know if you need any further information.
Thanks for your help

Comment: mind showing some effort here?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that job with grep. Here's one way to do it with GNU awk for multi-char RS and the 3rd arg for match():

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { RS="\\s*</[^>]+>\\s*" }
match($0,/^<path\s*action="D"[^>]+>(.*)/,a) { act = a[1] }
/^<msg>xyz$/ { print act }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
/Demo/svn_dev/src/classes/Admin.cls
```

Answer (score 0):

with `grep` you can condition on existence of the first pattern to extract the second, need a little bit after work to extract the information

```
$ grep -q '<msg>xyz</msg>' file && grep -A1 'action="D"' file | 
  sed -n -r '$s/[^>]*>(.*)<.*/\1/p'

/Demo/svn_dev/src/classes/Admin.cls
```

however, all might fail if your line breaks are different from the posted text.  Perhaps better to use xml aware tools.